# OpenMP critical based on some condition

Tags: openmp

I'm pretty sure my question is poorly worded, and am unsure how to word it. Perhaps someone more experienced can edit my question description so its more accessible to others.

I have an array of ints, say `int x[5000]` and several threads which perform operations on this array. For example, suppose each thread will loop through the elements of this array and increment each entry by 1.

I want to prevent race conditions, that is, two threads shouldn't be writing to the same element in the array at the same time. They can write to *different* elements of the array at the same time, but not to the same element. I could use an OpenMP block as follows:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < x.size(); i++){
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            x[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't allow different threads to write to different elements even though I want to allow the threads to be able to do that (since the array entries are independent of each other). Is there some OpenMP construct that will make it so that the threads are allowed to write to different entries of the array at a time, but not to the same particular entry at the same time?

If someone can refer me to a similar question (wasn't sure what to search), that would also be appreciated.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I would like each thread to loop through the whole array. Wouldn't Doing what you suggest would cause the for loop to be split among the threads, resulting in a single total loop through the array?

Comment: This is a simplified version of a more specific problem I'm trying to solve. I have an array. I have threads doing work with that array. The entries of the array are independent of each other, but sometimes two threads might do something to the same entry at the same time, which I want to prevent. That is all. How can I do this with OpenMP?

Comment: This minimal  code example makes no sense on any level. It is hard to understand what is needed from the code, why even have the parallel then? what is x shared? or split workload to each thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do what you describe is

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0 ; i < x.size(); i++) {
        x[i] += 1;
}
```

This automatically splits the loop and gives each thread its own value of i. You have to be careful though as you can still easily introduce a race condition.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 1 ; i < x.size(); i++) {
        x[i] += x[i-1]; //race
}
```

Suppose ThreadA is working on the iteration where `i = 2` and ThreadB is working on the iteration where `i = 3`. ThreadA and ThreadB both access `x[2]` at the same time, which as you noted is bad.

It is up to you the programmer to ensure your OpenMP code is race free. There is not any automatic way of keeping your code safe.